# Faster way of finding intersection of lists in a dataframe rather than going row by row?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops, optimization

I have two pandas dataframes, both with the same two columns, where each element is a list.  Something like:

df1:

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|        col_a        |        col_b     |
|---------------------|------------------|
|   [A1, A2, A3, A4]  |        [B1]      |
|---------------------|------------------|
|   [A1, A2, A3, A4]  |      [B2, B3]    |
|---------------------|------------------|
|         [A5]        |      [B2, B3]    |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

df2:

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|        col_a        |        col_b     |
|---------------------|------------------|
|       [A2, A4]      |      [B1, B2]    |
|---------------------|------------------|
|         [A5]        |      [B2, B4]    |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

Each row represents a set of combinations, meaning that Row 1 of of df1 represents the combinations A1-B1, A2-B1, A3-B1, and A4-B1.  What I want to do is go row by row to get a unique set of combinations that exist in both df1 and df2, but still kept in this list representation.  I do not want each row representing a unique combination.

The output for the example would look like:

output:

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|        col_a        |        col_b     |
|---------------------|------------------|
|        [A2, A4]     |        [B1]      |
|---------------------|------------------|
|        [A2, A4]     |        [B2]      |
|---------------------|------------------|
|         [A5]        |        [B2]      |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

The way I'm doing this right now involves a nested for loop that loops over each row in df1, each row in df2, and finds the intersection between the two lists, which is then appended to an empty list.

Here's the code:

```
# initialize two empty lists, one for each column
col_a_intersect = []
col_b_intersect = []

# loop over both dataframes to find intersection of lists row by row
for index_1, row_1 in df1.iterrows():
  for index_2, row_2 in df2.iterrows():
    col_a_intersect.append(list(set(row_1['col_a'])& set(row_2['col_a'])))
    col_b_intersect.append(list(set(row_1['col_b'])& set(row_2['col_b'])))

# create a dataframe of the two lists that are now populated
output = pd.DataFrame(
  {col_a: col_a_intersect,
   col_b: col_b_intersect})
```

The code works as expected, however, it takes a very, very long time to run.  I'm working on a dataset of ~20K by ~100K, and this has been running for about 18 hours now.  CPU and RAM usage have been negligible, so the task itself isn't very resource intensive.  I suspect the long duration is due to the use of a for loop, which are generally frowned upon.  Is there a faster way to do the task that I have described?

Answer (score 2):

With this type of data, you wouldn't get much vectorization. That said, you can explode both columns and do a merge, followed by a groupby:

```
(df1.reset_index()
    .explode('col_a').explode('col_b')
    .merge(df2.explode('col_a').explode('col_b'), on=['col_a','col_b'])
    .groupby(['index'])
    .agg(lambda x: list(x.unique()))
)
```

Output:

```
          col_a col_b
index                
0      [A2, A4]  [B1]
1      [A2, A4]  [B2]
2          [A5]  [B2]
```

Comment: Got it.  The reason why I would want to avoid blowing it up during any step is because the resultant dataframe is very large row wise (~40M rows) which goes over the RAM in the machine.